# AWS Lambda function with Node issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've been working on a AWS Lambda function using Node 8.10.  I noticed that I'm able to import the aws-sdk, but I had some issues with firing some of the EC2 functions.   I have a role set up with a policy to allow my function access.  Here's where I'd like some additional understanding.

I tried to start an instance like this...

```
let params = { InstanceIds: ["i-31112345d325"] };

 try{
    let response = ec2.startInstances(params);
    response.send();
}catch(ex){
    console.log(ex);
}
```

and like this...

```
 ...
 try{
    let response = ec2.startInstances(params, function(err, data){
      if(err) console.log(err);
      else //do something else
    });
 );
}catch(ex){
    console.log(ex);
}
```

neither one of these methods seem to trigger the EC2 machine to start.  I did some digging and pulled out the promise() and it seems to work.

```
try{
    await ec2.startInstances(params).promise().then((response)=> {
        console.log("Success with ", response);
    })
}
catch(ex){
    console.log(ex);
}
```

I changed nothing else.  Most of the code I've seen around the internet does it the first 2 ways.  Can someone explain why this doesn't work for me?  The documentation doesn't seem to address it and the examples in the docs don't seem to work for me.  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#startInstances-property)

Comment: Guess: only the last variant waits for the SDK function to return. Other variants return before the function finishes invoking and the Lambda function is killed once the async call of the SDK function is submitted.

Comment: Your handler function... which of these is it? `exports.handler = (event, ...` or `exports.handler = async (event, ...`

Comment: At the time, I was using an async handler.  I've since removed it and it seems to work when I include the function callback now.

Comment: I've figured out the issue was my knowledge of how the handler works.  I'll update with the answer to help those in the future who come across the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Node 8.10 the handler function supports a `callback` method.  You can use that `callback` to tell the Lambda when to terminate from within the callback function or promise

```
      'use strict';
      const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
      var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();
      exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
              var params = {  InstanceIds: ["i-1234567890abcdef0"]}
              ec2.startInstances(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) callback(err.stack); // an error occurred
                else     callback(null, data);           // successful response
                });
              }
```